# Implement route specific middleware

Tags: php, psr-7

I've managed to use the **[request-handler](https://github.com/middlewares/request-handler)** combined with **[aura-router](https://github.com/middlewares/aura-router)** with a single *[router handler](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router/blob/3.x/src/Map.php#L225)*.

Am trying to implement route specific middleware, as opposed to the 'global' application middleware.

```
$routerContainer = new RouterContainer();
$map = $routerContainer->getMap();

// Works fine...
$map->get('index', '/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index');

// Error: Invalid request handler: array
$map->get('index', '/', [
    new SampleRouteMiddleware(),
    'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index'
]);

$request = ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals($_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_FILES);

$requestContainer = new RequestHandlerContainer();

$dispatcher = new Dispatcher([
    new SampleAppMiddleware(), // applies to all routes...
    new AuraRouter($routerContainer),
    new RequestHandler($requestContainer),
]);

$response = $dispatcher->dispatch($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want to with the PSR-15 implementation you are using. Your only option would to be write a Middleware with the following structure:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface as Middleware;

class SampleMiddleware implements Middlware
{
    public function process(Request $request, Handler $handler): Response
    {
        if ($this->supports($request)) {
             // Do something specific to your middleware
        }

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        // Write the conditions that make the SampleMiddleware take action. i.e.,
        return $request->getPath() === "/sample";
    }

}
```

Only requests whose path is "/sample" will be processed by this middleware.

Comment: But frameworks like Slim and Laravel are able to accomplish such behavior. I guess I still have to do some digging into their works

Comment: Correct. That is why I talked about the PSR-15 implementation you are using.

Comment: You think it's still achieveable with PSR-7 like middleware!